# how to reduce the number of points from a huge data collection based on the closest distance?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, data-visualization, points

I am a beginner in python coding, my main area of work is earth sciences. I have a huge database (million of points) that contain coordinates (x,y) expressed in UTM (this is not critical for the problem I am describing) that represent center of circles with a radius r. I would like to reduce the number of these point based on a threshold value that is expressed in terms of multiple radius (for example 1*r / 2*r / 3.5*r, etc.); Points that would be closer than the threshold should be rejected from the points list. I would like to create a new mask channel that will show 1 for the points accepted and 0 for rejected points and also plot the results as circles (points as center) with radius r both the original set of points and the new accepted channels points in different colors in a graph (labeled axis / title / summary legend). before starting the processing data points should be sorted out in ascending order. I would like be able to export graph as images and pdf maps.
#

1. List item

   - data would be something like:
   - xy_data=
   - [[ 687690.,  992340.],
   - [ 687720.,  992340.],
   - [ 693210.,  993000.],
   - [ 693420.,  999420.],
   - [ 693450.,  999420.],
   - [ 693480.,  999420.],
   - [ 693540.,  999210.],
   - [ 693570.,  999210.],
   - [ 693840.,  999870.],
   - [ 693870.,  999870.],
   - [ 693900.,  999870.],
   - [ 694200., 1000530.],
   - [ 694230., 1000530.],
   - [ 694260., 1000530.],
   - [ 694890.,  999240.]]
   - ...
   - ...
   - ...

please see at the bottom what I have tried which is according to me a poor way to code. Please suggest a better python way to accomplish this task.

Thank you in advance for your help and assistance (please provide explanation for each step and do not hesitate to suggest readings that would help in understanding the programing part)

```
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.spatial import distance
    from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist


    r           = 100.
    k           = 0
    N           = xy_data[:].shape[0] # xy_data is input data as shown above          
    dist_tol    = 3*r
    Mask        = np.ones(N)
    sep         = np.ones(N) # points separation
    point_dist3 = np.ones(N).reshape(1,N)

    for i in np.arange(k,N - 1,1):

        if i == 0 :
            point_dist3[:,i] = 0.
            sep[i]           = 0.
            Mask[i]          = 1.

        for j in np.arange(i+1,N,1):
            print('i: ',i, '\tj: ',j, '\tk: ', k)
            sep[j]  = cdist(xy_data[i:i+1], xy_data[j:j+1])
            if sep[j] <= dist_tol: #if point_dist2[:,i] <= dist_tol:
                Mask[j] = 0
                k       = j
            else:
                 continue
```

Comment: Hello, Ali, welcome to Stack Overflow.  One of the first questions you'll be asked is "What have you tried?"  Stack Overflow is for helping people stuck in a problem when all attempts at a solution have failed or you are just plain stuck.  We typically don't just give out solutions for free with no effort on behalf of the person asking the question.  So, what have you tried?  If you have no idea where to start, that's okay too.  Just let us know.

Comment: My coding skills is not great. I have tried first to calculate the distance between points using a double loop (starting from first point compared with the rest of points) and cdist method but it so inefficient that it takes a huge amount of time to go through the process. To be honest I am not even sure if it does the job properly, at this point I am so frustrated...